# Enzyme Test React.createRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, chai-enzyme

I have a commponent where I use the new `React.createRef()` api, how to test `document.activeElement` should be equal current ref commponent.

component :

```js
export class Automatic extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => this.focusContainer()
    componentDidUpdate = () => this.focusContainer()

    container = React.createRef()
    focusContainer = () => this.container.current.focus()

    render = () => {
        return (
            <div
                name='automatic'
                onKeyPress={this.captureInput}
                onBlur={() => setTimeout(() => this.focusContainer(), 0)}
                ref={this.container}
                tabIndex={0}
            >
               ...
            </div>
}
```

old testing (works):

```js
it('should focus container on mount', () => {
    automatic = mount(<Automatic classes={{}} />, mountContext)

    document.activeElement.should.be.equal(automatic.ref('container'))
})
```

new one (doesn't work):

```js
it.only('should focus container on mount', () => {
    const container = React.createRef()
    automatic = mount(<Automatic classes={{}} />, mountContext)

    document.activeElement.should.be.equal(automatic.ref(container.current))
})
```

Answer (score 7):

> Updated with working examples. Added a styled-components example.

Here's how I solved it with Jest (uses different assertions, but concept is the same):

```js
// setup
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div>
        <span ref={ref}>some element</span>
    </div>
))

// test
it('should contain the forwarded ref in the child span', () => {
    const ref = React.createRef()
    const component = mount(
        <Fragment>
            <MyComponent ref={ref} />
        </Fragment>,
    )

    expect(component.find('span').instance()).toEqual(ref.current)
})
```

- The idea is to get the instance of the element that has the `ref`.
- It seems to only work when wrapping `MyComponent` in another element, I used `Fragment`.

I ran into some trouble when using **Styled-Components. This is because it creates a number of extra elements. Try debugging with `console.log(component.debug())`. It will show you what enzyme renders.

When debugging you'll see that Styled-Components uses the [recommended way](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components) to forward props.

You can find the right element using the property selector for `forwardedRef`:

```js
// setup
const El = styled.div`
    color: red;
`

El.displayName = 'El'

const MyComponentWithStyledChild = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <El ref={ref}>some element</El>
))

// test
it('should contain the forwarded ref in a rendered styled-component', () => {
    const ref = React.createRef()
    const component = mount(
        <Fragment>
            <MyComponentWithStyledChild ref={ref} />
        </Fragment>,
    )

    // Styled-components sets prop `forwardedRef`
    const target = component
        .find('[forwardedRef]')
        .childAt(0)
        .instance()

    expect(target).toEqual(ref.current)
})
```

- You can use the same trick if you created a Higher order Component (HoC) where you need to pass `ref`

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should focus container on mount', () => {
  automatic = mount(<Automatic classes={{}} />, mountContext)

        document.activeElement.should.be.equal(automatic.instance().container.current)
    })
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).